# Pandas df `to_gbq` with nested data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, etl

I'm working in a limited Airflow environment in which I don't have access to `google-cloud-bigquery` but do have access to `pandas-gbq`. My goal is to load some JSON API data using some schema involving records into a BigQuery table. My strategy is to first read all the data into a pandas dataframe using a dictionary to represent the records: e.g.

| uuid | metadata1 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | {u'time_updated': u'', u'name':u'jeff'} | ... |

Then, I've been trying to use `pandas_gbq.to_gbq` to load into BQ. The issue is I get
`Error at Row: 0, Reason: invalid, Location: metadata1, Message: This field: metadata1 is not a record.` and I realize this is because from the [Google Cloud website](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) it says that pandas-gbq *"Converts the DataFrame to CSV format before sending to the API, which does not support nested or array values."*

And so I won't be able to upload a dataframe with records to BQ in this way since again I can't use `google-cloud-bigquery` in my environment.

What would be the best strategy for me to upload my data to BQ (around 30k rows and 6 or so columns with 8ish nested fields each)?

I know this sounds like a very bad strategy but I could upload a flattened version of all fields ini a record as a single string to the BQ table and then run a query from my code to replace these flattened fields with their record-form versions. But this seems really bad since for a time, the table would contain the wrong schema.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right, you'll have to use google-cloud-bigquery instead. Per the same link you provide above, pandas-gbq still does not support nested fields.